# Update async intill key pressed

Tags: .net, async-await

This is a console application.

//Pseudocode

```
While loop{

UpdateData() ;
PrintData() ;

Wait(update Interval) ;

}
```

I need the loop and the Wait() to break/return when a button is pressed.
But the wait can't block listening for keypress.

I assume async await could solve this but maybe its better with Timer class?

I'm looking for a current best practice for handling this situation.

This is my code at the moment, but im pretty sure its not the way to go and it seems to affect the main thread from where it comes. My idea is that this StatMonitor method should not finish untill the async PrintUser whhile loop has finished.

```
        public async void StartMonitor()
    {
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var keyboardListenTask = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var key = Console.ReadKey();

            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel(false);

        }, cancellationTokenSource.Token);


        while (!cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var userActor = ChooseUserActor();

            while (!cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                PrintUser(userActor);

                Console.WriteLine("Any key to go back...");
                try
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: IS this a Windows Form project? WCF? UWP? Please provide more information.

Comment: Sorry. I've updated op.

Comment: Ive also added some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for a current best practice for handling this situation.

If you want to refresh the display periodically while waiting for user input, then put the refresh in a `Timer` and wait for user input the regular way (calling `Console.ReadKey()` on the main thread).

While you can build alternative solutions using `async`/`await`, `Task.Delay`, and `CancellationToken`s, that would just be adding complexity for no real benefit.